# WKWebview Delegate methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

updating my code from UIWebView to WKWebview but having this error on my delegate methods

```
Nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'null_unspecified'
```

here is my code an showing this error on `navigation`

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
  // Show & animate the activity indicator.
  _webView.spinner.hidden = NO;
  [_webView.spinner startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you redeclare somewhere this delegate method, probably in delegate header, so find it and use as original

```c
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation;
```